# Behavior QT translate tr() method with arguments (%1)

Tags: qt, translation

Will dynamic translation work for such a code:

`const QString myText = tr("%1 Hello World").arg(someVar);`

I have few doubts:

1: Will the translation entry be generated for above code (when running lupdate). If yes, will the "%1" argument part be ignored?

2: Is the above code correct ? Should the dynamic part be translated separately before using it in the argument with tr. Provided we know all possible value of someVar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your run lupdate, you will see this in your .ts file:

```
<source>%1 Hello World</source>
```

The translator will need to know they can just ignore the '%1' part.

If `someVar` is a number, there is no need to do anything else. If it's a string, it will need to be translated separately.

Comment: Lets say my current language is Spanish, then tr ("%1 Hello World") will return a QString = " %1 Hola Mundo"
Now we can replace the %1 with anything we want. (Either a number or other translated string).
Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: How the sameVar string values should be translated separately?

Comment: @AndreaGiudiceandrea have you tried wrapping it in `tr()`?

Comment: I think tr(someVar) cannot work correctly.